# We need a mail client for sending notification emails via ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

We need to send out thousands of emails per day via `ActionMailer` in our Rails app. These will be sent upon receipt of user interaction in our app. Gmail Enterprise limits at 2,000 per day, this simply will not be enough for us, and thus we cant use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail isn't intended or appropriate for large amounts of bulk mail. At the volumes you want to send, you need a dedicated provider designed for buik mailings. There's plenty of providers that do this, but [SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com) is a popular option, and can handle very large volumes.

Comment: SendGrid has a really nice POST-back API where you can track events (i.e. delivered, bounced). I like it.

Comment: Yeah, we use the SendGrid postback api and I was shocked how straightforward it was to get integrated.